# How do I create more than one folder in a specific folder without repeating the path name?

Tags: bash

How can I create more than one folder within a folder with the `mkdir` command? More specifically, lets say, I want to create three new folders - `config`, `views` and `controllers` in a folder that has path `public/articles`. This is what I am currently doing in bash:

```
> mkdir public/articles/config public/articles/views public/articles/controllers
```

What I want to know is if there is a shorter way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
mkdir -p public/articles/{config,views,controllers}

# can be nested
mkdir -p public/articles/{config,{view,controller}s}
```

Comment: Or `mkdir -p public/articles/{con{fig,trollers},views}` :)

Answer (score 1):

With a subshell:

```
(cd public/articles; mkdir config views controllers)
```